# How to test the behavior of std::memory_order_relaxed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, atomic, memory-barriers

I have read the doc of [std::memory_order_relaxed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

One part of explanation of *Relaxed ordering* is ....

> ```
> // Thread 1:
> r1 = y.load(memory_order_relaxed); // A
> x.store(r1, memory_order_relaxed); // B
> // Thread 2:
> r2 = x.load(memory_order_relaxed); // C 
> y.store(42, memory_order_relaxed); // D
> ```

and the explanation of this is said ...

> [It] is allowed to produce `r1 == r2 == 42`. In particular, this may occur if D is completed before C in thread 2, either due to compiler reordering or at runtime.

I have understood the explanation, and try to test on my computer as following code:

```
std::atomic<int> x = {0};
std::atomic<int> y = {0};

int r1, r2;

void task1() {
    // Thread 1:
    r1 = y.load(memory_order_relaxed); // A
    x.store(r1, memory_order_relaxed); // B
}

void task2() {
   // Thread 2:
    r2 = x.load(memory_order_relaxed); // C 
    y.store(42, memory_order_relaxed); // D
}


int main()
{
    std::thread t2 (task2);
    std::thread t1 (task1);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    cout << "r1: " << r1
        << "\nr2: " << r2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The results of this code is **never** `r1 == r2 == 42`, which is said that it's a possible behavior in that doc.

Is there any wrong in this code? Or, is there any misunderstanding?

Comment: It is *possible* that I will win 1000000 in the lottery tomorrow. But it is not *likely*. I can try all my life and never hit the jackpot. *Someone* however will win it.

Comment: The memory ordering on x86 is at minimum acquire-release. So you will not see `r1==r2==42` on a classical computer. Maybe if you target an ARM CPU you could see it.

Comment: @Olive That's not precisely true. The *hardware* will never reorder these operations, but the compiler is allowed to reorder them (on different atomics), according to the language specification. The observed behavior depends on whether the compiler *actually* does that.

Comment: @Oliv: Also on multi-socket setups? You typically have limited non-uniform memory access; each memory module connects directly to only a single CPU.

Comment: @ArneVogel In theory yes. But until nowaday, all compilers treats atomics as if they were also declared volatile. For exemple, compilers do not even optimize away two successives stored on a single atomic performed inside the same function, even if the standard alowes that.

Comment: @MSalters That kind of beast does not belong to my definition of classical computer! You are lucky to run with this kind of horse!

Comment: @Oliv: They're actually not very exotic. A twelve-core Xeon is more than twice as expensive as a pair of six-core Xeons, makign the dual-socket choice sensible for those that are not burdened by weird licenses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Or, is there any misunderstanding?

Yes there is one. What `std::memory_order_relaxed` allows in your program is for an implementation (a compiler) targeting an architecture, to produce a program which may observe the side effect `r1 == r2 == 42`.

An implementation does not have to produce such a program, and such a program does not have to produce that side effect; it is a possible outcome anyway.

> How to test the behavior of std::memory_order_relaxed?

I cannot see a general solution to this question. You can only check that the side effect *you* observes matches with the specs of `std::memory_order_relaxed`.

Comment: It seems the same results of using *memory_order_relaxed* and *memory_order_seq_cst* in high level implementation instead of low level (like compiler). So, when should *memory_order_relaxed* be actually used ? Or, generally, is it just okay to use default memory_order (seq_cst) in high level ?

Comment: @eric_hsu it's well explained in the page you linked: _The default behavior of all atomic operations in the library provides for sequentially consistent ordering (see discussion below). That default can hurt performance, but the library's atomic operations can be given an additional std::memory_order argument to specify the exact constraints, beyond atomicity, that the compiler and processor must enforce for that operation._

Comment: @eric_hsu you may be operating on an architecture which *always* guarantees sequential consistency for atomic operations. Or the relative timings of your various threads have not yet occurred *just so* in a manner that causes the behaviour you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a bit naive because by the time the 2nd thread starts the 1st one may have completed. The threads need to run these pieces of code truly concurrently.

For `r1 == r2 == 42` to be true it requires load `C` to be reordered past store `D`, x86 does not do *loads reordered after stores* currently, so that you may never observe this kind of reordering on this platform (unless the compiler reorders `C` with `D`).

ARM and PowerPC, on the other hand, have weaker memory models. See [Runtime memory ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Runtime_memory_ordering)
 table.

Comment: This is imprecise for the same reason as Oliv's previous comment is. See my reply in the question's comment thread.

Comment: @ArneVogel I do not think your comment is accurate. In particular, _the hardware will never reorder these operations_ is false on PowerPC and ARM.

Comment: Context matters… I responded to Oliv's statement about *x86*. The point however is that the C++ implementation (i.e. in this case, usually, the compiler) may also reorder relaxed operations on different atomic variables, even if the hardware guarantees acquire-loads and release-stores, unless other synchronization mechanisms are used. IOW, `r1 == r2 == 42` is actually possible on x86.

Comment: @ArneVogel The compiler can reorder `C` and `D`, true. But I fail to see a reason why it would do so here. There must be a reason for the compiler to do this reordering (e.g. faster code, register pressure).

Comment: Indeed, there's no reason here to do or not to do it. The standard simply allows it, but generally it allows several kinds of behavior of atomics that don't actually happen in practice. An extreme example are the infamous ["out-of-thin-air" loads](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/atomics#order-9), which are discouraged ("should" vs. "shall"/"must") but not forbidden.